# SDWebImage - Change ActivityIndicatorView Colour?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I am currently using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and have just started to add in the `sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView` feature however, is there a way I can change the colour of the progress indicator to like red?

I've tried to change the colour in `UIView+WebCache.m` inside the `sd_addActivityIndicator` function `setTintColor:` and `setColor:` but has no effect. The colour of the indicator is still grey/white.
Im coding in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

*for future generations:*

```
let loader = SDWebImageActivityIndicator()
loader.indicatorView.color = .blue
yourImageView?.sd_imageIndicator = loader
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that using:

```
[imageView sd_setIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```

For more information about the available options check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityindicatorviewstyle?language=objc) of `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle`.

Comment: Understood yes, however I want to change it to like red for instance.. I have tried `setTintColor` and `setColor` but has no impact.

Answer (score 0):

```
       import SDWebImage

 extension UIImage {
    func loadImageWithUrl(url: URL, placeholderImage: UIImage) {
                let loader = SDWebImageActivityIndicator()
                loader.indicatorView.color = .red
                self.sd_imageIndicator = loader
                self.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: { img, error, cacheType, newUrl in
                    self.image = error == nil ? img : placeholderImage
                })
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 